# Modifying a while loop that contains a break statement

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to write a loop to keep extracting each line from an input file using `getline`, and keep running until it detects the end of a paragraph.

I found this as a reference:

```
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
   if (line.empty())
      break;

  else
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++)
     {
        //Doing stuff here
     }
  }
}
```

I've tested this and it runs fine. However, I'm not allowed to use break statements for my assignment.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    while (!line.empty())
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
     }
 }
```

But the program ends up crashes when the loop iterates for the first time. I was wondering if anyone had some input how I could resolve this issue

Comment: I'd suggest putting a double condition in the first while loop. `while (getline(inFile, line) && parsing)` Setting `parseing` to false would stop the while loop much like a break statements.

Comment: Your second attempt doesn't ever finish because when the first line isn't empty the inner while loop continues checking the same line isn't empty for ever.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you solve it:

```
while (getline(inFile, line) && !line.empty()) { ... }
```

it has the exact same effect and it arguably improves the readability. The problem with your approach is that it causes an infinite loop. The fact that `line.empty()` evaluates `false` does not effect the outer `while` there.

Comment: This code exits on the first empty line, even when more non-empty lines are in the file.

Comment: @2785528 how do we know that's not what OP wants to do?

Comment: Agreed.  Maybe he will see your comment and provide a decision.

Answer (score 1):

The following also demonstrates the use of a stringstream for testing.  exec contains 3 tests snippets.

```
int exec(int , char** )
{
   int retVal = 0;
   cout << "\n\n";

   string s =
      "  now is the time\n"
      "  for all good men\n"
      "\n"                       // empty line
      "  to come to the aid \n";  // eof()

   // solution 1 has infinite loop
   if(0) // disable
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << s;      // load ss

      string line;
      while (getline(ss, line))
      {
         while (!line.empty())
         {
            for (uint j=0; j < line.length(); ++j)
               cout << line[j];
         }
         cout << endl;
      }
   }

   // solution 2 exits too soon, line 3 is empty, line 4 dropped
   {
      cout << "\n\n";
      stringstream ss;
      ss << s;      // load ss

      string line;
      while (getline(ss, line) && !line.empty())
      {
         cout << line << endl;
      }
   }
   // output: 
   //  now is the time
   //  for all good men


   // solution 3 - small test effort, but seems to work
   {
      cout << "\n\n";
      stringstream ss;
      ss << s;      // load ss

      do
      {
         string line;
         getline(ss, line);  // read a line

         if (!line.empty())       // test it has content
            cout << line << endl; // use when non-empty

      } while(!ss.eof());    // how continue when file has more lines

   } // solution 3 seems to work
   // output: 
   // now is the time
   // for all good men
   // to come to the aid        

   return retVal;
}
```

Comment: getline() retrieves all chars in the line, except the eoln char ( '\n' ),  The 3rd line of input string 's' will result in empty line.